# Pandas read_csv response codes when using an external url

Tags: python, pandas, python-requests, http-status-codes

I'm replacing `requests.get()` with `pd.read_csv()` and would like to write some exception logic if pandas does not get the equivalent of a status code 200.

With requests, I can write:

```
response = requests.get(report_url)
if response.status_code != 200:
```

How can I apply the same logic to `pd.read_csv()`? Are there any status codes I can check on?

Comment: Don't you get an error if `read_csv` fails with a URL?

Comment: I'm not sure how to test this outside of passing an incorrect URL which doesn't test exactly what I want to check against.

Comment: you can't get status code with `read_csv()` - it simply raise error when it can't read it. You have to use `requests.get()` to check status and get data from url and later use `read_csv( io.StringIO( text ) )`. Or you should use `try/except` to catch error when it can't read data.

Comment: Hmm, that's odd. I can pass an external URL to `read_csv()` so I'd assume their goal with this feature was to replace any need for `requests`.

Comment: you can use url in `read_csv()` but this function doesn't have method to gives you status code. It simply raise error when it can't read url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `url` in `read_csv()` but it has no method to gives you status code. It simply raises error when it has non-200 status code and you have to use `try/except` to catch it. You have example in other answer.

But if you have to use `requests` then you can later use `io.StringIO` to create file-like object (file in memory) and use it in `read_csv()`.

```
import io
import requests
import pandas as pd

response = requests.get("https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/csv/addresses.csv")

print('status_code:', response.status_code)

#if response.status_code == 200:
if response.ok:
    df = pd.read_csv( io.StringIO(response.text) )
else:
    df = None

print(df)
```

---

The same way you can use `io.StringIO` when you create web page which gets `csv` using `HTML` with `<form>`.

---

As I know `read_csv(url)` works in similar way - it uses `requests.get()` to get file data from server and later it uses `io.StringIO` to read data.

Comment: I had forgotten to add ```io``` to my answer, but you already did, I deleted it because yours is a lot more complete.

Comment: Actually looks like this is the route I'm going to take. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is to write a custom reader that makes it possible to check that a URL is valid before reading it although this defeats the purpose

```
import requests
def custom_read(url):
    try: 
        return_file = pd.read_csv(url) 
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as err:
        raise
    else:
        return return_file
```

A valid URL will work

```
my_file = custom_read("https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/csv/addresses.csv")
```

This fails and raises a `requests` error

```
my_file1 = custom_read("https://uhoh.com")
```

Otherwise, there is no way to access the status code of a URL for a `DataFrame` object once it has been read.

Comment: Aw, that just seems inefficient having to run two http requests.

Comment: @Bonteq you can use `read_csv( io.StringIO( response.text ))` instead or running `read_csv(url)`

Comment: Sorry, I have edited, you only need to check that a requests error was raised. @Bonteq

Comment: @furas I think you're right, that's probably the best route here.

Comment: @NelsonGon How does that snippet handle a non-200 status code?

Comment: It will always raise the relevant code via the HTTPError api. You can customize it if you wish to check for specific status codes but this takes you back to obtaining  a response first @Bonteq

Comment: @Bonteq when `read_csv` has non-200 status code then it raises error and you have to use `try/except` to catch it